# Doesn't output the result in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I wanted to write a code that converts from rubles to dollars and euros. It seems that everything was written normally, but the translation result does not output. It seems to me that the whole problem comes from the fact that I somehow wrote the wrong **button Text **, or an incorrect condition check. Here is the code:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.275"
        android:id="@+id/solution"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEur"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="EUR"
        app:cornerRadius="32dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.895"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.525">

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnUsd"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="USD"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:cornerRadius="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.139"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.525">

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.996"
        android:id="@+id/result"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView result;
    EditText solution;
    MaterialButton usd, eur;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        solution = findViewById(R.id.solution);
        usd = findViewById(R.id.btnUsd);
        eur = findViewById(R.id.btnEur);
    }

    void assignId(MaterialButton btn, int id) {
        btn = findViewById(id);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        MaterialButton button = (MaterialButton) view;
        String buttonTxt = button.toString();

        if (buttonTxt.equals("USD")) {
            String usd = solution.getText().toString();
            double usd1 = Double.parseDouble(usd);
            usd1 = usd1 / 74.76;
            String usd2 = String.valueOf(usd1);
            result.setText(usd2 + " DOLLAR");
        }
        if (buttonTxt.equals("EUR")) {
            String eur = solution.getText().toString();
            double eur1 = Double.parseDouble(eur);
            eur1 = eur1 / 79.61;
            String eur2 = String.valueOf(eur1);
            result.setText(eur2 + " EURO");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to write **return** after each **if**, but it didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

First, i don"t understand the utility of assignId, it's never used.
Secondly i think that would be easier to do that :

```
  TextView result;
EditText solution;
Button usd, eur;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    solution = findViewById(R.id.solution);
    usd = findViewById(R.id.btnUsd);
    eur = findViewById(R.id.btnEur);

    usd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String usd = solution.getText().toString();
            double usd1 = Double.parseDouble(usd);
            usd1 = usd1 / 74.76;
            String usd2 = String.valueOf(usd1);
            result.setText(usd2 + " DOLLAR");
        }
    });

    eur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String eur = solution.getText().toString();
            double eur1 = Double.parseDouble(eur);
            eur1 = eur1 / 79.61;
            String eur2 = String.valueOf(eur1);
            result.setText(eur2 + " EURO");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Strange, it doesn't work that way either. I think I have something wrong in xml, but I don't know what

Answer (score 0):

use this xml code with my code and that will work :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.275"
        android:id="@+id/solution"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/result"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.996"
        android:id="@+id/result"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUsd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/result"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnEur"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```